# web cookies use to track last five visited pages in php

Tags: php, cookies

I trying to display last five visited pages in website.I have products section in my website and it has a drop down list with 10 products.

On the main page, I want to display the last five previously visited products.
I am using Word Press for developing the website. 
Please refer to my code below :

```
<?php

 extract($_POST);

 $visitcount=1;
 setcookie('visitcount',1+$_COOKIE['visitcount'],time()+60*60);
 $visitcount = $_COOKIE['visitcount'];
 echo  "Number of views: ".$visitcount;

 ?>
```

Whereas the code for my webpage is as follows:

```
<form action="/cookies.php" 
method="post" 
img class="wp-image-50 alignleft" 
src="http://adityabdhende.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/statue-of-liberty-_1_-300x225.jpg" 
alt="statue of liberty _1_" 
width="716" 
height="537"> 
</form>
```

In this code, when I click on the page it is accessing 'cookies.php' file.

I am not getting how to display the last five visited pages.

Comment: Be careful with `extract`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code of how you possibly can do it:

```
$currentProduct = $thePlaceYouCanTakeYourCurrentProductFrom;
$_COOKIE['productsList'][$visitcount % 5] = $currentProduct;
```

Then you can print it and do whatever you wish with it...

This is naive implementation though, if you want it to hold last 5 distinct products and not just the last 5, you can do it by comparing the last product, and holding separate count of times you update productsList.

Comment: please can you let me know what do you mean by $thePlaceYouCanTakeYourCurrentProductFrom; Does these variables have url to pages of the different products.

Comment: If you want it to just be the url, you might want to use for example $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , but you will need to do some manipulations on what you will get from it if you want it to look good